# jsRender template disappears after rendering

Tags: templates, jsrender

After I call `render` on my jsRender template, it seems to be consumed, and thus is removed from the DOM. This is frustrating as I have a page where the template needs to be rendered several times depending on user interaction.

```
console.log($('#tpl'));
$('#container').html($('#tpl').render(json));
console.log($('#tpl'));
```

The second console.log is an empty array, and I can confirm the template no longer exists using the DOM inspector and the exception that jsRender throws: `Uncaught JsRender Error: Unknown template: "#tpl"` -- the page must be reloaded to re-inject the template into the DOM.

How can I persist the jsRender template between renderings?

Comment: Obvious dumb question: Is the script element where you declared the template inside your container element? If so, of course calling .html() on the container will remove it... BTW you can also compile a template from a string. It doesn't have to be in a script element...

Comment: @BorisMoore Ah. Silly me. Somehow I blocked out the idea that the html() method would exclude `<script>` tags. That would do it, though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still not sure why it has to be consumed and simply can't stay in the DOM after rendering the first time, but I found a workaround. If anybody knows the reason for removing the template from the DOM, I'm still interested.

**Update: Actual answer** (Thanks, Boris)

My template was within my `#container` element, so the `html()` method was of course overwriting it. Silly me.

**<strike>Workaround</strike> Neat little trick anyway**

Using [this 'variant' example](http://borismoore.github.com/jsrender/demos/variants/accessing-templates/03_getting-template-objects-from-script-declaration.html), I saved the template in a local variable. Then I call `render` on the variable name instead of the jQuery selector:

```
var tpl = $.templates('#tpl');

.
.
.

console.log(tpl);
$('#container').html(tpl.render(json));
console.log(tpl);
```

This has *also* managed to preserve the template across renderings.

Comment: I've just wasted several hours of my time only to realise I made the exact same mistake! I can't thank you enough for posting this - I was practically tearing my hair out trying to understand what was going wrong..

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar problem today where I had two target divs and two script block templates in the body.  My problem was that I hadn't closed the div element tags correctly (too much xaml) and the result was the second template was never rendered as it couldn't be found.

Here's a JsFiddle showing the correct  usage (rather than the /> self-closing syntax):

http://jsfiddle.net/jgoldsmith/XvvPC/

Hope that helps someone else.